# Docker ~ Install SQL Express on microsoft/windowsservercore

Tags: sql-server, docker

As a proof of concept, I am trying to set up a docker container running SQL Express along with some other services on the microsoft/windowsservercore base image.

I have managed to get to the point where I am able to build the image without any problems. However, when I try to run the image, I get the following error message, which I can't make heads nor tails of:

```
PS C:\Docker Data Directory\SQL Test> docker run sqltest --name sqltest_container -p 1433:1433
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 1afb908fe2902885211f24c7fd2f9817122e7a1
dd67008eebd0f4c63e31e3ddf encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file
 specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"--name sqltest_container -p 1433:1433","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\install","CreateStdInPipe
":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Starts with the windows servercore base image
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

# Exposes port 1433
EXPOSE 1433

# Sets the Working Directory
WORKDIR /install

# Downloads SQL Express Installer
RUN powershell wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/7/907AD35F-9F9C-43A5-9789-52470555DB90/ENU/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe  -OutFile sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe

# Installs Thw SQL Express Installer
RUN /install/sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe /q /x:/install/setup

# Add the SQL Test Installation Files (C:/SQLTest/SQLInstall/configurationfile.ini)
ADD SQLTest/SQLInstall C:/SQLTest/SQLInstall

#Installs SQL  Express
RUN /install/setup/setup.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile=C:/SQLTest/SQLInstall/configurationfile.ini
```

My configurationfile.ini looks like this:

```
[OPTIONS]
ACTION = "Install"
UPDATEENABLED = "False"
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE = "False"
FEATURES = SQLENGINE
INSTANCEDIR = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTANCEID = "SQLExpress"
INSTANCENAME = "SQLExpress"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE = "Manual"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE = "Automatic"
FILESTREAMLEVEL = "0"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT = "True"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS = "BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"
TCPENABLED = "0"
NPENABLED = "0"
```

I have also tried getting this to work with a number of tutorials, but in the end, I have always arrived at the "The system cannot find the file specified" error message.

My best guess at this point is that SQL Express requires some kind of perquisite that is not yet installed. But what puzzles me is why I can build the image, but not run it.

Any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

---

Additional Info 17-Oct-2018

I have now kept working on this, and noticed that at the end of the Dockerfile, the SQL Server SQLEXPRESS Service exists, but is in the stopped state.

```
Step 13/13 : RUN powershell get-service "MSSQL$*"
 ---> Running in 6aa3926abd3a

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS   SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
```

I have tried getting it to run with the following command added to the Dockerfile...

```
RUN powershell start-service "MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS"
```

...however, that only generates the following error message, to which I have not been able to find a working solution either:

```
start-service : Failed to start service 'SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
(MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControl
   ler:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
   .StartServiceCommand
```

Can anyone please help me with this? This is really driving me into despair by now...

---

Update 31-Oct-2018

Okay, so I figured out what the problem behind the ''The system cannot find the file specified'' error was:

The problem was an ultimately simple syntax error in the ''docker  run'' command that ultimately causes this misleading error message.

They syntax I used was:

```
docker run sqltest --name sqltest_container -p 1433:1433
```

However, the correct syntax is:

```
docker run --name sqltest_container -p 1433:1433 sqltest
```

Now I can run the container, but the SQL Express Service does not run inside it. I have confirmed that the service exists, but it does not start automatically, and trying to start it manually produces the following error message:

```
Step 9/11 : RUN powershell (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
 ---> Running in 6b2f50c860ee
SQLEXPRESS
Removing intermediate container 6b2f50c860ee
 ---> 14a4b7d42cd7
Step 10/11 : RUN powershell get-service "MSSQL$*"
 ---> Running in d8fba119d1ea

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Start... MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS   SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)


Removing intermediate container d8fba119d1ea
 ---> e656776ca44f
Step 11/11 : RUN powershell start-service "MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS"
 ---> Running in 9f66a24a99c1
start-service : Failed to start service 'SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
(MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControl
   ler:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
   .StartServiceCommand
```

Comment: Any update on this? Also have you tried the SQL express docker images? I also see in some docker-compose files `MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED: "true"` so possibly there are some other services SQL express service relies on. Also, are you running SQL locally? I ask because maybe there is a port conflict.

Comment: Also, not seeing where you specified your service accounts. According to the docs they are required - Minimal example 'setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="<DomainName\UserName>" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="<StrongPassword>" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="<DomainName\UserName>" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS'